# React Native - dynamically create new component onPress

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm looking to dynamically create a new component every time the user clicks a button.

```js
export default function WorkoutCard({ children }) {
    const [workoutNum, setWorkoutNum] = useState([1]);

    const addSets = () => {
        setWorkoutNum(workoutNum.push(workoutNum.length + 1));
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <AppText style={styles.exerciseHeader}>{children}</AppText>
            {workoutNum.map((num) => (
                <WorkoutTextInput workoutNum={num} />
            ))}
            <Divider></Divider>
            <Button title="Add set" style={styles.add} onPress={addSets} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to create an array which is also going to have the following values [1,2,3,4...] when the user clicks the button. But I'm getting the following error when I press the button - 'Undefined is not a function'.

Any tips on how I can fix this please?

Comment: Im not totally sure, but could you try change onPress={addSets} by onPress={addSets()}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem: push()

The problem is the method [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).  The method mutates the array and returns the length of the new array.  It does not return the array itself.

```
setWorkoutNum(workoutNum.push(workoutNum.length + 1));
```

When you call this, you are changing your state from an `array` `[1]` to a `number` `2`.

### Solution: concat() or spread

You need to set your state to a new array.  You can do this with spread notation `[...state, newVal]` or with [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).  The concat method creates a new array and does not mutate the existing one.

```
setWorkoutNum(workoutNum.concat(workoutNum.length + 1));
```

```
setWorkoutNum([...workoutNum, workoutNum.length + 1]);
```